# AutoHotkey v1 use one shortcut as switch control given loop action on or off

Tags: autohotkey

I am making a macro for a game I play, in where I can sit watching a terminal.

I hope when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> it presses <kbd>E</kbd> on the terminal, it scrolls down so screen can show the item mouse needs to click, then clicks given coordinate and waits 20 seconds. (repeat forever until press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to stop)

```
!p::
while toggle==0
    (send e)
    Loop 3
        send {WheelDown}
    send {click,1210,670}
    Sleep, 20000
!o:: toggle=(toggle+1)
```

However it keeps the <kbd>E</kbd> key held down indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

The reason <kbd>e</kbd> appears to be being held is because your while-loop is only executing the "`(send e)`" line. If you need the while-loop to execute more than one line of code, enclose the [code block](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Block.htm) in brackets. Also, unless your individual hotkeys are one line, you'll want to put a `Return` at the end each; otherwise, it will continue to execute into the next hotkey's code and so on.

Here is my untested version of your code. Please let me know if this works for you.

```
!p::
While !toggle
{
    Send , e{WheelDown 3}{click , 1210 , 670}
    Sleep , 20000
}
toggle := !toggle
Return
!o::toggle := !toggle
```